# Putting Application on windows Startup with out User interaction in java

Tags: java, desktop-application, startup

I have one Application Developed in Java. is there any way that i can start that application on user login. I can do it by putting Start up. but is there any way to put there application auto in startup with out user interaction? means i want to put that into the Start up with some java program is it possible?

Comment: You at lest 3 basic options, the first is to create a batch file sch runs your jar, the second is to use some kind of native executable wrapper to wrap your jar(s) in which is then placed in the startup folder, the third is to use some kind of jni/jna process to create a lnk (shortcut) that can run Java for yr an execute your application jar

Comment: If you're thinkiing of using a native executable wrapper of some kind, you might even be able to install the program as a service

Comment: how that will be possible @MadProgrammer i dont have idea about it. and how do i do that? and how to create this .batch file?

Answer (score 1):

In windows you need to register a program as a service to have it launch at startup time.

Kosuhke wrote winsw for Glassfish while at Sun which I've used for a couple of years and found easy to use and reliant when the configuration file is in place.

https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw

Comment: but i have not use that is that a demo that u have given link??

Comment: Actually, you can place a executable program in the users start up folder and even place an entry in the registry, a service is just one way to do this

Comment: it dont know even how to start this :( but okey so i need to put this program?

Comment: that is right that i need to put that application in start up folder but how it would be happen auto??

Comment: On rereading the question this is for having a program start without having a user needing to log in.  This is not exactly what you ask for (but may be what you eventually need :) ).